# What do alternate floors do?

Tags: let-it-die

I just went to the second floor from Ikegara and despite being my 10th or so time doing so, this time I went to a place called Wanoki rather than the usual Imokawa-Cho. What's the difference between going to Imokawa-Cho and Wanoki? I noticed there are other divergent paths further up the Tower of Barbs, so I'm curious. Do I get better rewards when going up certain paths versus others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you traverse the Tower of Barbs you'll more often find diverting pathes heading both up and down to floors off of the main elevator.  The rewards each floor can grant seem more linked to what tier of floors you are in (1-10, 11-20 and so on) but at some points these other routes are necessary for overall progress upwards through the unlocking of gates and taking down midbosses.  Something that was incredibly useful to check that the game didn't teach me for a while is to press down on the d-pad to bring up both a floor map and tower map to help find alternate escalators or plot an overall route you want to take.

Comment: Yes, I've actually discovered the answer to this question on my own since I posted but this is useful information for others! Also the down button on the D-pad was extremely useful to know. I only just discovered that recently! Prior to that, exploring floors was such a chore because I got lost very often.